# How to send data to REST dataset in Azure Data Factory Dataflow?

Tags: rest, apache-spark, http-post, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use a REST Service as a Sink Dataset in my Dataflow, but it always fails with a Bad Request 400 Error.
[image: sink overview]
[image: sink settings]
[image: Dataflow activity settings]

Error

{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: DF-REST_001 - Rest - Error response received from the server (url:https://my_url,request body: Some({"Name":"GREST"}), request method: POST, status code: 400), response body: Some({"error":{"name":"badRequest","message":"Request body has invalid format."}}))","Details":"com.microsoft.dataflow.Issues: DF-REST_001 - Rest - Error response received from the server (url:https://my_url,request body: Some({"Name":"GREST"}), request method: POST, status code: 400), response body: Some({"error":{"name":"badRequest","message":"Request body has invalid format."}}))\n\tat com.microsoft.dataflow.Utils$.failure(Utils.scala:75)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.rest.RestClient.ensureSuccessResponse(RestClient.scala:430)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.rest.RestClient.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$rest$RestClient$$executeRequest(RestClient.scala:415)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.rest.RestClient.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$rest$RestClient$$executeSingleRowRequest(RestClient.scala:153)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.rest.RestClient$$anonfun$savePartitionSingle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(RestClient.scala:106)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasource"}

Answer (score 0):

The status code 400 is a Bad Request error, and the server cannot process the request due to an error.

The possible reasons might be due to incorrect URL, malformed syntax, request body might have invalid JSON. Please check the URL and validate JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

When you use copy activity and the method is POST, make sure that you send it in Additional headers section key -> "Content-Type" value -> "application-json"
[image]